# Cron Job Using Codeigniter And CLI

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, codeigniter-3

i have a function that need run every day at 00:00 AM,
i do some research but not any result coming up with my cron job.

this is my function code :

```
public function aro()
 {
      $this->deposito_m->exec_aro();
      echo 'oke';
 }
```

my deposito_m is:

```
function exec_aro()
 {
      $tgl_now = date('Y-m-d');
      $data = $this->get_data_deposito_aro($tgl_now);
      if (!empty($data)) {
           foreach ($data as $x) {
                $transaksi = $x->tgl_transaksi;
                $tgl_awal = substr($transaksi, 0, 10);
                $jenis_ang = $x->jenis_ang;
                $tanggal_berakhir = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+" . $jenis_ang . " months", strtotime($tgl_awal)));
                $anggota_id = $x->anggota_id;
                $akun = $x->akun;
                $dk = $x->DK;
                // $tanggal_berakhir = $x->tgl_berakhir;
                $kas_id = $x->kas_id;
                $user_name = $x->user_name;
                $nama_penyetor = $x->nama_penyetor;
                $no_identitas = $x->no_identitas;
                $alamat = $x->alamat;
                $jumlah_awal = $x->jumlah;
                $conf_bunga = $this->bunga_m->get_key_val();
                $bunga_deposit = $conf_bunga['suku_bunga_deposit'];
                $pajak = $conf_bunga['pajak_depo'];
                $bunga = $jumlah_awal * ($bunga_deposit / 100) * ($x->jenis_ang / 12);
                $total_bunga = $bunga -  ($bunga * ($pajak / 100));
                $jumlah = $jumlah_awal + $total_bunga;
                $create_arr = array(
                     'tgl_transaksi' => $tgl_now,
                     'anggota_id'    => $anggota_id,
                     'jenis_ang'     => $jenis_ang,
                     'jumlah'        => $jumlah,
                     'keterangan'    => 'new',
                     'akun'          => $akun,
                     'DK'            => $dk,
                     'kas_id'        => $kas_id,
                     'tgl_berakhir' => $tanggal_berakhir,
                     'update_data'   => $tgl_now,
                     'user_name'     => $user_name,
                     'no_identitas'  => $no_identitas,
                     'alamat'        => $alamat,
                     'nama_penyetor' => $nama_penyetor,
                     'status'        => 'on_progress',
                );
                $this->db->insert('tbl_trans_dep', $create_arr);
           }
      } else {
           return 'tidak ada data';
      }
 }
```

and my controller is :

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Deposito_status extends OperatorController
{
     public function __construct()
     {
          parent::__construct();
          $this->load->helper('fungsi');
          $this->load->model('deposito_m');
          $this->load->model('general_m');
     }

     public function index()
     {
          $this->data['judul_browser'] = 'Data Deposito';
          $this->data['judul_utama'] = 'Deposito';
          $this->data['judul_sub'] = 'Status Deposito';

          //table
          $this->data['css_files'][] = base_url() . 'assets/extra/bootstrap-table/bootstrap-table.min.css';
          $this->data['js_files2'][] = base_url() . 'assets/extra/bootstrap-table/bootstrap-table.min.js';
          $this->data['js_files2'][] = base_url() . 'assets/extra/bootstrap-table/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.js';
          $this->data['js_files2'][] = base_url() . 'assets/extra/bootstrap-table/bootstrap-table-id-ID.js';

          //modal
          $this->data['css_files'][] = base_url() . 'assets/extra/bootstrap-modal/css/bootstrap-modal-bs3patch.css';
          $this->data['css_files'][] = base_url() . 'assets/extra/bootstrap-modal/css/bootstrap-modal.css';
          $this->data['js_files'][] = base_url() . 'assets/extra/bootstrap-modal/js/bootstrap-modalmanager.js';
          $this->data['js_files'][] = base_url() . 'assets/extra/bootstrap-modal/js/bootstrap-modal.js';
          $this->data['js_files'][] = base_url() . 'assets/extra/bootstrap-modal/js/nsi_modal_default.js';

          // datepicker
          $this->data['css_files'][] = base_url() . 'assets/theme_admin/css/datepicker/datepicker3.css';
          $this->data['js_files'][] = base_url() . 'assets/theme_admin/js/plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js';
          $this->data['js_files'][] = base_url() . 'assets/theme_admin/js/plugins/datepicker/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.id.js';
          //$this->data['barang_id'] = $this->pinjaman_m->get_id_barang();

          //daterange
          $this->data['css_files'][] = base_url() . 'assets/theme_admin/css/daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css';
          $this->data['js_files'][] = base_url() . 'assets/theme_admin/js/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js';

          //select2
          $this->data['css_files'][] = base_url() . 'assets/extra/select2/select2.css';
          $this->data['js_files'][] = base_url() . 'assets/extra/select2/select2.min.js';

          //editable
          $this->data['css_files'][] = base_url() . 'assets/extra/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css';
          $this->data['js_files'][] = base_url() . 'assets/extra/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js';

          $this->data['jenis_ags'] = $this->deposito_m->get_data_angsuran();

          $this->data['isi'] = $this->load->view('deposito_status_v', $this->data, TRUE);
          $this->load->view('themes/layout_utama_v', $this->data);
     }
     public function ajax_deposito()
     {
          // $this->load->model('deposito_m');
          $out = $this->deposito_m->get_deposito();
          header('Content-Type: application/json');
          echo json_encode($out);
          exit();
     }
     function aksi()
     {
          $this->load->model('deposito_m');
          if ($this->deposito_m->deposito_aksi()) {
               echo 'OK';
          } else {
               echo 'Gagal';
          }
     }
     // function get_jenis_simpanan()
     // {
     //      $id = $this->input->post('jenis_id');
     //      $jenis_simpanan = $this->general_m->get_id_simpanan();
     //      foreach ($jenis_simpanan as $row) {
     //           if ($row->id == $id) {
     //                echo number_format($row->jumlah);
     //           }
     //      }
     //      exit();
     // }

     function get_jenis_angsuran()
     {
          $id = $this->input->post('jenis_ang_grid');
          $jenis_angsuran = $this->general_m->get_jns_angsuran();
          foreach ($jenis_angsuran as $row) {
               if ($row->ket == $id) {
                    echo number_format($row->jumlah);
               }
          }
          exit();
     }

     public function aro()
     {
          $this->deposito_m->exec_aro();
          echo 'oke';
     }
}
```

my crontab -l in server is :

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /home/admin/web/kspspmi.dieselone.co.id/public_html/index.php deposito_status/aro
```

i try with * * * * * to know my cron is running or not, in log there is some CMD running but nothing happens with my data in database.

I try run my crontab script at my CLI and returning:

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR</p>
<p>Filename: core/Input.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 351</p>

</div><div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/admin/web/kspspmi.dieselone.co.id/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/Session.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 687</p>

</div><div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/admin/web/kspspmi.dieselone.co.id/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)</p>
<p>Filename: helpers/url_helper.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 542</p>
```

Can someone help me what is wrong or how to do cron job in server,
Thank you.

Comment: You're current not running that cronjob via Apache, but CLI (`/usr/bin/php`). Did you try to run the complete command from CLI? Does it work there? Is your script able to take CLI parameters? `index.php deposito_status/aro`

Comment: @brombeer yap i run complete command and returning like what i post sir, i just edit it second ago

Comment: Codeigniter Documentation has something: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/cli/cli.html?highlight=cron - this might help

Comment: @brombeer you have any suggest besides using CLI sir?

Comment: Use `wget` to fetch the URL via your webserver. (And don't assume I'm a sir)

Comment: @brombeer is that safe? do you have example with wget via webserver bro?

Comment: You can use `wget -q "http://your_cronjob_uri" -O /dev/null` . This `-O /dev/null` is to avoid creation of a output file